# ¿Cómo puedo darle fin a un juego en unity 3d?

Tags: unity3d

Tengo un juego 3d simple, consta en tomar 20 monedas, puse un mensaje de fin al tomar las monedas, pero como puedo darle un fin al juego, osea que todo se detenga y quizás poner un audio como pantalla del final

Comment: Procura poner mas informacion relacionada a tu problema. Una porcion de codigo o un ejemplo de las cosas que ya intentaste.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.